# C++ Macro: how to create an overrite?

Tags: c++, boost, macros, naming-conventions

So I found a need in using something like [Boost.Extension](http://boost-extension.redshoelace.com/docs/boost/extension/boost_extension/introduction.html) to keep my apps more open to new modules. But as soon as I got to [first tutorial](http://boost-extension.redshoelace.com/docs/boost/extension/boost_extension/tutorials.html) I found out that its syntax is quite not like I'm used to:

```
// Depending on the compiler and settings,
// it may be necessary to add a specific export
// declaration. The BOOST_EXTENSION_EXPORT_DECL
// adds this if necessary.
void BOOST_EXTENSION_EXPORT_DECL
boost_extension_hello_world(int repetitions) {
  for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; ++i) {
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

I want to make it possible to write something like  `void function` instead of `void BOOST_EXTENSION_EXPORT_DECL` it looks better and as i have AS3 background it will not look like something horrible for me.

So how to create an overrite for C++ macro not in header where it was defined but in your own C++ file?

Comment: LOL @ people answering an already answered question with the exact same thing that was already said.

Comment: @Crazy Eddie: its all about feedback and explanations end tips and warnings for dummy me.=)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace `BOOST_EXTENSION_EXPORT_DECL` by `function` with:

```
#define function BOOST_EXTENSION_EXPORT_DECL
```

Then you can use it by:

```
void function boost_extension_hello_world(int repetitions) {
  for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; ++i) {
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

But this could cause problems if your code contains the word `function`, because the compiler replace all occurrence of `function`.

Comment: you mean that if I am having a variable called "function" it would be replaced with BOOST_EXTENSION_EXPORT_DECL ?

Comment: Yes your variable would be replaced by BOOST_EXTENSION_EXPORT_DECL. I don't recommend to do it. Use a UPPERCASE and non generic name for macros.

Answer (score 1):

You could just write the following before:

```
#define function BOOST_EXTENSION_EXPORT_DECL
```

And then state the function like this:

```
void function
boost_extension_hello_world(int repetitions) {
  for (int i = 0; i < repetitions; ++i) {
    std::cout << "Hello World" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#define function BOOST_EXTENSION_EXPORT_DECL
```